# Spring AOP: Before method execution with Collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

**Case 1 (Works fine)**

I am trying to implement a `before` AOP implementation for the below method:

```
public void setNames(List names) {
    this.names = names;
}
```

I tried this:

```
<aop:pointcut id="empl" expression="execution(* com.model.Employee.set*(java.util.List)) and args(names)"/>
    <aop:aspect ref="aspect">
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="empl" method="beforeExecutionEmpl" arg-names="names"/>
    </aop:aspect>
```

And it worked.

**Case 2 (Does not works)**

But if I change the method to this (Added the Generics):

```
public void setNames(List<String> names) {
    this.names = names;
}
```

and this:

```
<aop:pointcut id="empl" expression="execution(* com.model.Employee.set*(java.util.List<java.lang.String>)) and args(names)"/>
    <aop:aspect ref="aspect">
        <aop:before pointcut-ref="empl" method="beforeExecutionEmpl" arg-names="names"/>
    </aop:aspect>
```

Then I an getting the below exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 44 in XML document from class path resource [spring-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "expression" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at com.aop.App.main(App.java:19)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The value of attribute "expression" associated with an element type "null" must not contain the '<' character.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:195)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:174)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:388)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(XMLScanner.java:1414)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.scanAttributeValue(XMLScanner.java:932)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanAttribute(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:460)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:277)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2755)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:648)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:140)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:511)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:808)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:737)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:119)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:235)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:284)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
... 14 more
```

Please suggest how to make the `Case 2` work since I want to use generics in my code.

Comment: Did you try in case 2 to leave the aop declaration untouched ?

Comment: yes I tried that but it did not worked!!!

Comment: According to [Pointcut not working for generic interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131910/pointcut-not-working-for-generic-interface), because of type erasure, the type of the generic should be ignored by AOP ... But unsure of it, and currently have no access to a development box ...

Comment: I agree with the reference that you provided. But I am not sure why it is not working in my case. If I remove the generic `String` then `<aop:pointcut id="empl" expression="execution(* com.model.Employee.set*(java.util.List)) and args(names)"/>` work but when I add the generic `String` then it does not works. Any pointers?

Comment: I tried googling "spring aop pointcut generic" and found you could try `...set*(Java.util.List+) ...`. But still unsure and cannot test anything :-(

Comment: Tried but did not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests with SpringFramework 3.2.4, and aspectjrt and aspectjweaver 1.7.4

I could not exactly reproduce your problem. Your pointcut expression in case 2 is effectively incorrect and should be written (without `<...>`)

```
<aop:pointcut id="empl" expression="execution(* com.model.Employee.set*(java.util.List)) and args(names)"/>
```

provided in your **interface**(*) you have

```
public void setNames(List<String> names);
```

and in you aspect

```
public void beforeExecutionEmpl(List<String> names) {
//
}
```

That's what I did in my tests and I got no error and the advice was effectively called. I must admit that even if signature in aspect is `public void beforeExecutionEmpl(List<Integer> names)` aspect is called too, but there can be errors at execution when using elements of the list because they are `Strings`.

(*) as you are using Spring AOP, I assume the pointcut is on an interface ...