# Exclude an exception from log

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, spring-aop

How can I exclude a specific exception from being logged in aspectj?

We're using spring security, so we've have an implementation of UserDetailsService.
When a user enters a username that does not exist, spring throws `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException`.
we want to exclude that specific exception from the log, but not the class it is thrown from (implementation of UserDetailsService).

For example in the following log, we want only the first line (entering...UserDetailsServiceImpl) and not the errors that follow.

```
22 Jun 2014 14:20:35  INFO LoggingAspect - Entering: ...UserDetailsServiceImpl  Method name: loadUserByUsername Method arguments : [***]
22 Jun 2014 14:20:42 ERROR LoggingAspect - Unhandled exception caught: ...service.UserDetailsServiceImpl    loadUserByUsername
org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException: User with loginName: *** doesnt exist
at ...UserDetailsServiceImpl.loadUserByUsername(UserDetailsServiceImpl.java:30)
...
```

Is there a way to do that with spring AOP?

EDIT:
This is what we have in the LoggingAspect:

```
@AfterThrowing(pointcut = "execution(* ..*.*(..)) && !methodsExcludedFromLog()", throwing = "exp")
public void afterThrowing(JoinPoint joinPoint, Throwable exp) {
...
}
```

I this I need to somehow change the `throwing` to exclude the spring exception, but I'm not sure how to do that.

EDIT 2:
So as suggested in the comments,  I tried adding a filter in log4j, but it doesn't seem to work, and the exception doesn't get filtered out. anyone know what the problem might be?

```
<appender name="consoleAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1} - %m%n" />
    </layout>
</appender>

<appender name="fileAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">
    <param name="append" value="false" />
    <param name="file" value="${catalina.home}/logs/MYAPP.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{ABSOLUTE} %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n" />
    </layout>
    <filter class="org.apache.log4j.filter.ExpressionFilter">
        <param name="expression" value="EXCEPTION ~= org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException" />
        <param name="acceptOnMatch" value="false"/>
    </filter>

</appender>

<root>
    <level value="INFO" />
    <appender-ref ref="consoleAppender" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</root>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share your source code and configuration and explain your request?

Comment: See my edit. is it clearer now?

Comment: Why use AOP for that? If you have a good logging package like Logback you can implement filters to exclude unwanted messages. http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html

Comment: Can you post a stack trace and highlight somehow the parts you don't want? Or don't you even want the stack trace?

Comment: @Bart we're already using AOP for other purposes, and we don't have Logback. Also, see my edits.

Comment: You really need to post your configuration and/or relevant source code. What is this LoggingAspect? Is your class, some other class? How are you configuring it? What is the pointcut it's acting on? What is the advice?

Comment: I'm really not sure what's the configuration you're referring to...the aop xml?

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100740/spring-aop-before-method-execution-with-collection) one SO post where the poster mentioned what code he has, what he tried, what he wants to achieve, the exception that is being thrown. I see you have a LoggingAspect that you probably want modified to intercept some exceptions and some not. If you want us to give you suggestions, you need to show what you actually have that needs adjustments. What is so difficult to understand?

Comment: Obviously, you intercept some calls with that LoggingAspect, but how do you expect us to suggest something specific given that you don't show the actual code that needs changes.

Comment: I edited my original post, there's no need to be rude.

Comment: And if you do in your afterThrowing() method something like `if(exp instanceof UsernameNotFoundException) { //do nothing } else { logException(); }`...

Comment: we can do that, obviously, but I thought there might be a more elegant way using aspectj

Comment: You don't need logback to apply filters, log4j(1 and 2) both support filters as well. Why hack your code with aspectj/spring aop to filter out some exceptions from logging. Your aspect is applied to everything and checked for each exception, adding additional performance overhead to all your method calls, especially nasty when the method is passing multiple methods which are targeted with this aspect. From my view you are trying to achieve things what you can already achieve with the logging framework used.

Comment: You may be able to do it with some arcane approach using AOP but you'd end up with potentially unreadable code.  AOP pointcuts should be targeting the static structure of your code and you're looking to use it to do runtime type checking.  This likely doesn't fit in the "15%"(Kiczales) that AOP does for you.  You could likely modify your static structure, but then you'll have a more complex solution.  Use the right tool for the right job (logging framework).  This is not a nail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you can only use

```java
{
    if (e instanceof UsernameNotFoundException)
        return;
    // Log exception
}
```

at the beginning of your advice. There is no syntactic way in either AspectJ or Spring AOP to somehow use jokers or boolean expressions in the "throwing" part. There you only have the option to either capture all exceptions or implicitly narrow down the selection to one specific type (and its subtypes) by binding the thrown exception to a typed variable. If you think about it, how should you bind an object to a variable having multiple types?

Whether you like it or not, this is the correct answer. I cannot change AspectJ syntax and semantics for you now. :-)